# Access package variable after its name is removed from symbol table in Perl?

Tags: perl

I tried delete the name of a package variable from the `main::` symbol table as below, but seems later code could still reference the variable, why it can be referenced after deletion? What's the effect of removing a name from symbol table?

```
$n = 10;
delete $main::{'n'};
print $n;
```

Comment: It seems like you want to remove/undef slots from typeglob; `perl -MData::Dumper -we '@n = 1..3; $n = 10; undef *n; print Dumper \@n, $n'`

Comment: @Сухой27 Could you show some more details about the difference between remove the symbol and remove/undef slots from typeglob?

Comment: `*n` is package typeglob holding slots for `$n, @n, %n, &n`. AFAIK `delete $main::{'n'}` deletes typeglob from package but slots can still be accessed as @ysth pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When perl code is compiled, globs for package variables/symbols are looked up (and created as necessary) and referenced directly from the compiled code.

So if you delete a symbol table entry `$pkg::{n}`, all the already compiled code that used `$pkg::n`, `@pkg::n`, etc., still use the original glob.  But `do`/`require`'d code or `eval STRING` or symbolic references won't.

This code ends up with two *n globs; all the code compiled before the delete executes will reference the original one; all the code compiled after will reference the new one (and symbolic references will get whichever is in the symbol table at that point in runtime).

```
$n = 123;
delete $::{n};
eval '$n=456';
print $n;
eval 'print $n';
```

Another example:

```
$n = 123;
sub get_n { $n }
BEGIN { delete $::{n} }
$n = 456;
print get_n();
print $n;
```